# Laravel 4 relationships on pivot tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

[image: Schema for Professor-Teaching-Subject]

Above is the current schema that is on my mind.

Each professor (faculty), will teach more than one subjects. The `faculties_has_subjects` table is the pivot table linking the two. On top of that, the pivot relation should have an attribute to store which semester it was taught in.

Sample data for the `semesters` table is:

```
+----+------------------+
| id | name             | 
+----+------------------+
| 1  | Fall 2010-2011   |
+----+------------------+
| 2  | Winter 2010-2011 |
+----+------------------+
| 3  | Fall 2011-2012   | 
+----+------------------+
| 4  | Winter 2011-2012 | 
+----+------------------+
```

How do I use laravel's Eloquent ORM to extract the following details for a particular faculty.

- Subjects Taught
- Semester in which each subject was taught

I could do it easily if instead of `semesters_id`, there was `semester_name` directly. But since this is a foreign key in the pivot table itself, how do I use Eloquent ORM with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot

Comment: I'm curious why people go the triple pivot route instead of attaching the relationship to the pivot table itself? E.g., if I have user_group why don't I do user_group_awards with award_id | user_group_id?